# baseUrls, redirects and rewrites in blogdown

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown, netlify

Hello blogdown stackoverflow community!

I have been recently migrating my personal GitHub/Jekyll blog (https://blogs.nopcode.org/brainstorm) over to Blogdown/Netlify, but I'm a bit confused by the `_redirects` and `config.toml` url routing business.

I have read in detail the official blogdown and [netlify documentations](https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/).

As well as Yihui's recommendations on [good permalink hygiene](https://yihui.name/en/2017/11/301-redirect/)

Unfortunately, no matter how many sensible changes I try (essentially on `config.toml` and `_redirects`), I cannot successfully migrate from Jekyll since:

1. Visiting https://blogs.nopcode.org/brainstorm results in all blogpost links rendered as `https://blogs.nopcode.org/brainstorm/brainstorm/2017-09-01-blogpost-etc` (two `brainstorm`'s in the URL instead of just one). I would like all my blogposts to link to `https://blogs.nopcode.org/brainstorm/2017-09-01-blogpost-etc` (just one brainstorm). Right now I'm doing a URL rewrite so that when a user clicks on one of those `brainstorm/brainstorm` links, it gets rewritten as simply `brainstorm`... clearly suboptimal.
2. I have to move parts of the theme (js/images/css/etc..) under `static/brainstorm/` in order for theme assets to load and find those URLs.

Here is the repo of my blog, should you find obvious flaws in it:

https://github.com/brainstorm/brainblog

And a string of changes I tried chasing an acceptable configuration without too many contortions:

https://github.com/brainstorm/brainblog/commits/master

That all being said, I find Hugo/blogdown super fast and the RStudio Addins menu/interface super handy to make quick changes on blogposts :)

Thanks much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is created because there is a relative path to posts at `brainstorm` and you are setting your base url to `https://blogs.nopcode.org/brainstorm`

Hugo will build your relative paths to the `baseURL` based on the theme configuration and Netlify will publish the public directory relative to the root of the site.

Hugo Server is showing you the correct links locally at `brainstorm/brainstorm`, because it configures the paths based on the baseURL.

The Netlify paths are from the root of the published site and is unaware of the Hugo configuration. On Netlify, the path to the posts are at `/brainstorm`.

### Possible Solution

- Create a layout for the home page of your site to create the list like the theme does for a Section.
- Put all posts into the content root and remove the `brainstorm` folder
- Have Hugo build to `public/brainstorm` using `hugo -d public/brainstorm` in the `netlify.toml`

Create `_index.md` file at the root of the `content` folder with any frontmatter data you want to use on the page, if any.

Create a `layouts/index.html` file at the root of your project repository.

```html
{{ partial "header.html" . }}

<main class="content" role="main">

  <div class="archive">
    {{ range .Data.Pages.GroupByDate "2006" }}
    <h2 class="archive-title">{{ .Key }}</h2>
    {{ range .Pages }}
    <article class="archive-item">
      <a href="{{ .RelPermalink }}" class="archive-item-link">{{ .Title }}</a>
      <span class="archive-item-date">
        {{ .Date.Format "2006/01/02" }}
      </span>
    </article>
    {{ end }}
    {{ end }}
  </div>

</main>

{{ partial "footer.html" . }}
```

Comment: Understood the problem. What would be a good/cleanest combination of settings/parameters to attain what I want to achieve?

Comment: I added to the answer, but have not had time to test. I am also not sure how this layout would affect the blogdown setup.

Comment: sorry to bother you after one year without touching this.... Sure I missed something on https://github.com/brainstorm/brainblog/commit/724c6b385184e3b04d7119b7c7ad1448352898bc... but it is still 404'ing :/ ... interesting thing is that when I launch it with the local `netlify dev` tool (https://www.netlify.com/products/dev/), it does work... but fails when it's live :_/

Comment: commented on your git repo with a pr of a working fix on the talves_fix branch.