# New blogdown posts showing on R-Studio, not rendering on Netlify? How to debug?

Tags: rstudio, hugo, blogdown, netlify

I've added a couple of blogposts to my blogdown/netlify backed site today:

https://github.com/brainstorm/brainblog/blob/master/content/brainstorm/2018-03-12-umccr-arteria.md

https://github.com/brainstorm/brainblog/blob/master/content/brainstorm/2018-03-13-umccr-pcgr.md

And while they render/preview successfully on R-Studio:

[image: R-Studio preview]

Those two blogposts do not show up on Netlify-hosted site after pushing/deploying (see deploy log below). *Even a manual deploy triggering (with clear cache checkbox on), fails to update the index page accordingly to show the two new posts:

[image: Netlify live blog]

From Netlify's side, this is a successful deployment, [along with all previous pushes from github](https://github.com/brainstorm/brainblog/commits/master), as far as I can see from their web console:

```
4:17:37 PM: Build ready to start
4:17:39 PM: Fetching cached dependencies
4:17:39 PM: Starting to download cache of 65.2MB
4:17:39 PM: Finished downloading cache in 625.456927ms
4:17:39 PM: Starting to extract cache
4:17:40 PM: Finished extracting cache in 1.126872353s
4:17:41 PM: Finished fetching cache in 1.869794305s
4:17:41 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
4:17:41 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
4:17:42 PM: Found netlify.toml. Overriding site configuration
4:17:42 PM: Different build command detected, going to use the one specified in the toml file: 'HUGO_BASEURL='https://blogs.nopcode.org/brainstorm' hugo' versus 'hugo' in the site
4:17:42 PM: Starting build script
4:17:42 PM: Installing dependencies
4:17:43 PM: Started restoring cached node version
4:17:45 PM: Finished restoring cached node version
4:17:46 PM: v8.10.0 is already installed.
4:17:47 PM: Now using node v8.10.0 (npm v5.6.0)
4:17:47 PM: Attempting ruby version 2.4.3, read from .ruby-version file
4:17:48 PM: Using ruby version 2.4.3
4:17:48 PM: Using PHP version 5.6
4:17:48 PM: Installing Hugo 0.37.1
4:17:50 PM: Installing missing commands
4:17:50 PM: Executing user command: HUGO_BASEURL='https://blogs.nopcode.org/brainstorm' hugo
4:17:50 PM: Building sites …
4:17:50 PM: 

4:17:50 PM:                    | EN
4:17:50 PM: +------------------+-----+
4:17:50 PM:   Pages            | 221
4:17:50 PM:   Paginator pages  |   0
4:17:51 PM:   Non-page files   |   0
4:17:51 PM:   Static files     |  45
4:17:51 PM:   Processed images |   0
4:17:51 PM:   Aliases          |   0
4:17:51 PM:   Sitemaps         |   1
4:17:51 PM:   Cleaned          |   0
4:17:51 PM: Total in 283 ms
4:17:51 PM: Caching artifacts
4:17:51 PM: Started saving pip cache
4:17:51 PM: Finished saving pip cache
4:17:51 PM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
4:17:51 PM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
4:17:51 PM: Started saving maven dependencies
4:17:51 PM: Finished saving maven dependencies
4:17:51 PM: Started saving boot dependencies
4:17:51 PM: Finished saving boot dependencies
4:17:51 PM: Build script success
4:17:51 PM: Starting to deploy site from 'public'
4:17:58 PM: Starting post processing
4:18:07 PM: Finished processing build request in 28.354802492s
4:18:12 PM: Post processing done
4:18:12 PM: Site is live
```

On Netlify's defense, this could be a symptom of [baseUrl issues not being fully solved yet, as I pointed out in an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49050417/url-redirects-and-rewrites-in-blogdown-coming-from-jekyll)... any hints very welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently after re-triggering a deploy today, one of the posts showed up, which leads me to believe that this is a timezone difference issue.

A consequence of Australia living in the future compared with the rest of the world X"D

Answer (score 3):

The missing posts are due to the date of your front-matter being in the future.

**Note:** The build will use the Netlify build server's time.

Today's date is `2018-03-12`

```
date: '2018-03-13T16:00:00.000000+00:00'
```

Run the Hugo command `hugo server --buildFuture` to see which posts will build on later deploys.

Comment: Today is 13th in Melbourne, Australia ;) Thanks for the `--buildFuture` hint/flag!

Comment: It will be based on the Netlify build server's time, I will add that to the answer.

Comment: how does one run `hugo server --buildFuture` on netlify?

Comment: You can't use `hugo server` on Netlify, because it is a development server for local, but you could use `hugo --buildFuture` as a build command on Netlify. I would not do that in most cases, because it shows drafts also.

Answer (score 2):

Just leaving this answer here in case anyone else is as dumb as me... if you can see the post in Rstudio but not on netlifies, make sure that `draft:no` in your `yaml`.